# Updating a table column based on the content of another column in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have below table (to simplify I only show a piece of the tables as an example, not all their content):

```
CREATE TABLE InstArtRel
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    idIns INT,
    ExpDateRev DATE,
    codArticle NVARCHAR(4),

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO InstArtRel (idIns, ExpDateRev, codArticle) 
VALUES (17400, datefromparts(2018, 10, 1), 'X509'),
       (17400, datefromparts(2020, 12, 2), 'X529'),
       (17400, datefromparts(2016, 9, 10), 'T579'),
       (17400, datefromparts(2017, 6, 7), 'Z669'),
       (10100, datefromparts(2019, 8, 17), 'TG09'),
       (10100, datefromparts(2018, 3, 28), 'TG09'),
       (10100, datefromparts(2018, 4, 24), 'TG09'),
       (10100, datefromparts(2016, 7, 12), 'TG09');        


CREATE TABLE Installations 
(
    idIns INT NOT NULL,
    DateIns DATETIME,

    PRIMARY KEY (idIns)
);       

INSERT INTO Installations (idIns, DateIns)
VALUES (17400, '2020-12-01'),
       (10100, '2022-05-07');
```

For each idIns in table Installations I need to update its `DateIns` column with the `ExpDateRev` column in `InstArtRel` table based on the following assumptions:

- If all `codArticle` column values for an `IdIns` in `InstArtRel` table are the same, then `DateIns` column in table `Installations` will be updated for the corresponding `idIns` with the maximum value of `ExpDateRev`.
- Otherwise, if all `codArticle` column values are NOT the same for an `IdIns` in `InstArtRel` table, then the `DateIns` column in table `Installations` will be updated for the corresponding `idIns` with the minimun value of `ExpDateRev`.

Better an example... taken into account that said above, the result in this case will be:

```
idIns | DateIns
------+-----------
17400 | 2016-9-10
10100 | 2019-8-17
```

Comment: @DaleK In fact I do not know how to proceed. I was thinking of making a kind of group by idIns.

Comment: Check my answer. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Aggregate` with `CASE` will help you.

**Query:**

```
SELECT idIns,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT codArticle) = 1 THEN MAX(ExpDateRev)
            WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT codArticle) != 1 THEN MIN(ExpDateRev) END DateIns
FROM InstArtRel
GROUP BY idIns
```

**Output:**

```
| idIns |    DateIns |
|-------|------------|
| 10100 | 2019-08-17 |
| 17400 | 2016-09-10 |
```

**UPDATE Query:**

```
UPDATE I
SET I.DateIns = R.DateIns
FROM Installations I
JOIN (
    SELECT idIns,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT codArticle) = 1 THEN MAX(ExpDateRev)
                WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT codArticle) != 1 THEN MIN(ExpDateRev) END DateIns
    FROM InstArtRel
    GROUP BY idIns
     )R ON R.idIns = I.idIns
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d7fe/5)